# How to add a data-attribute to a dropdown menu with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I have a standard dropdown list and am able to databind to the list.

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlMake" ClientIDMode="Static" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="URL" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
    <asp:ListItem>Select Make</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

I would like to add a data-attribute to the option like below:

```
<asp:ListItem data-siteid="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SiteID") %>">Select Make</asp:ListItem>
```

I'm obviously getting an error because it doesn't recognize the data-siteid.

**The list is databound.**

Any tips would be handy

Comment: If you bind DropDownList to some collection (say List<Things>) and objects stored in this collection (in this case Thing) have property SiteID then you should be able to access this property with the code you already have. Could you provide part of code with databinding?

Comment: Could you provide an example? I do have access to the data with the List, however I am not sure how to assign it since it isn't a valid value for <asp:DropDownList>

Comment: Sorry, I got it wrong. So are you trying to add your custom attribute to ListItem, right? Maybe you could use this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.attributes.aspx?

Comment: Also what exactly are you trying to accomplish? Maybe there's some other way to get the same result?

Comment: Yes, I ended up just building a repeater, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could do this in the code-behind.  I'm not sure if this is the most elegant approach, but it should work.

```
Dim dataSrc() As String = {"ABC", "123", "!@*#"}
drp.DataSource = dataSrc
drp.DataBind()
For i = 0 To drp.Items.Count - 1
    drp.Items(i).Attributes.Add("data-siteId", dataSrc(i))
Next
```

Also, if this is just something which is not databound, you could consider using the HtmlSelect control which should work as well:

```
<select id="drp2" runat="server">
  <option data-siteId="2">ABC</option>
  <option data-siteId="3">123</option>
  <option data-siteId="4">@*!&</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 4):

I ended up using a repeater since the page didn't need to repost.  This allowed me not to have to work with an ondatabound event.

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptDropDown">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <select id="ddlMake">
            <option value="">Select Make</option>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <option data-siteid="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SiteID") %>" value="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "URL") %>"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name") %></option>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </select>
    </FooterTemplate>        
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite it with pure html if no events handling is needed:

```
    <select>
      <%foreach (var item in DataSource){%>
        <option data-siteid="<%=item.SiteID%>" value="<%=item.Value%>"><%=item.Name%> </option>
      <%}%>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this (where `ds` is the dataset):

```
for (int row = 0; row <= ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1; row++) {
    ddl.Items(row).Attributes.Add("data-siteid", ds.Tables(0).Rows(row)("SiteID"));
}
```