# JQuery not returning Values from checkboxlist, returns state

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

please let me know what I can correct here, I'm locked in on something seemingly simple.

Using JQuery 1.6.2:

I am trying to return an array of VALUES of checked items in CheckBoxList.

Using modified examples from web I have the following, which returns an array of "on, on, on, on" (if all 4 checkboxes checked).

Shots.push($(this).prop('checked')) returns "true, true..."
Shots.push($(this).attr('Value')) returns "on, on..."

```
            var Shots = [];

            $('#cblShots').find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function () {
                Shots.push($(this).val());
            });

                if (Shots != "") {
                    $(Pnote).val(Shots.join(', '));
                } else {
                    updateTips("Please select at least one item");
                    return false;
                }


<asp:Panel ID="pnlAppointmentShotSelection" runat="server" style="display:none;">
    <label>Please select which shots you would like administered</label>
    <br /><br />
    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblShots" runat="server" CssClass="ShotList">
      <asp:ListItem Value="Flu">Flu</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Value="B-12">B-12</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Value="Pneumonia">Pneumonia</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Value="TDAP">Tetanus-Diptheria-Pertusis (TDAP)</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:CheckBoxList>
   </asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Can you add the final html code displayed on the browser?

Comment: first line example from the generated output:<td><input id="cblShots_0" type="checkbox" name="cblShots$0" /><label for="cblShots_0">Flu</label></td>

Answer (score 0):

Acording this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11834920/how-to-add-a-data-attribute-to-a-dropdown-menu-with-c-sharp) is available add data-attributes to ListItem, so try add data-name attributes to each element and then, try this in javascript :

```
var Shots = [];
$('#cblShots').find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function () {
      Shots.push($(this).attr("data-name"));
});
```

Comment: @user1457613 Can you add the final html code displayed on the browser?

Comment: Example of table 'cblShots' generated in IE: <table id="cblShots" class="ShotList" border="0">
   <tr>
    <td><span name="Flu"><input id="cblShots_0" type="checkbox" name="cblShots$0" /><label for="cblShots_0">Flu</label></span></td>
   </tr><tr>

Comment: Besides name is not valid attribute of ASP.NET listitem.

Comment: @user1457613 try use data-attributes, i updated my answer to use data-attributes