# add attribute other than value to DropDownList items when using SqlDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a DropDownList bound to a SqlDataSource as follows:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlist" AppendDataBoundItems="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="name" DataValueField="value" AutoPostBack="True" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:myConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [name], [value] FROM [myTable]" runat="server"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I would like to bind a third database column to another attribute (not value), say database table column `DefaultBit` to ListItem attribute `data-default` so that the DropDownList renders as

```
<select>
    <option></option>
    <option value="1" data-default="1">Line 1</option>
    <option value="2" data-default="0">Line 2</option>
</select>
```

I assume I need to do this programmatically in the code-behind file, but it's not clear to me if I would still bind a SqlDataSource to the DropDownList or if I should open a connection and iterate through the results using SqlReader and update the DropDownList "manually" or some other more elegant solution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11834920/how-to-add-a-data-attribute-to-a-dropdown-menu-with-c-sharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try following solution:

1. Add `DropDownList` and `SqlDataSource` mark up as (please note I have added `OnDataBound="ddlist_DataBound"` and third column in select statement)

   ```
   <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlist" AppendDataBoundItems="True" OnDataBound="ddlist_DataBound"
     DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="name" DataValueField="value"
     AutoPostBack="True" runat="server">
       <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
   </asp:DropDownList>

   <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" ConnectionString=
      "<%$ ConnectionStrings:myConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [name], [value],
      [DefaultBit] FROM [myTable]" runat="server">
   </asp:SqlDataSource>
   ```
2. Add code behind method  `"ddlist_DataBound"` as:(please note `row[0]` is name, `row[1]` is value and `row[2]` is DefaultBit)

   ```
   protected void ddlist_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e) {
       System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
       System.Data.DataView dv = (System.Data.DataView)SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
       dt = dv.ToTable();

       foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in dt.Rows) {
           ddlist.Items.FindByValue(row[1].ToString()).Attributes.Add("data-default", row[2].ToString());
       }
   }
   ```

I have tested it in an application and works beautifully.

Comment: I came to the same solution independently, so your answer gives me more confidence that this is the way to go.  I found; however, that running the code behind method onDataBound resulted in the attribute not surviving postbacks.  Instead I used onPreRender so that the attributes were added on every postback.