# How to display selected text on drop down list in 2 lines in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

I have a `dropdownlist` in asp.net webform with long values as its options. 
Every time I select a value, it  should be displayed on the `dropdownlist` field.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="addressDdl" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Width="210px">
 </asp:DropDownList>
```

I populate my dropdownlist using this method:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    List<address> addressAll = //get table data from SQL that has been returned as a list

    addressDdl.DataSource = addressAll;
    addressDdl.DataTextField = "address";
    addressDdl.DataValueField = "addressID";
    addressDdl.DataBind();
    addressDdl.Items.Insert(0,"--Select--");
}
```

However, since my `dropdownlist` is not long enough, it can only display parts of it. Is there any way so the `dropdownlist` is able to display the selected value in 2 lines?

Below is an example of the problem I face:

[image]

Comment: CSS size fixing in dropdownlist options may help: `select {width: n}` (n in pixels). Note that sometimes this is browser-dependent, another way to show full text with label inside `UpdatePanel` is available.

Comment: I did try the `dropdownlist` size fixing, however, all it did was making the `dropdownlist` to have more place to fit stuff in, now actually warping the text so it moves to the next line @TetsuyaYamamoto

Comment: Technically this isn't c# and it's not really asp.net either. You might get a wider spread of contributors if you tag it with HTML, css etc..

Comment: Is it a plain `select`, `asp:DropDownList` or AJAX toolkit combobox control? 2 former controls primarily uses CSS, but the latter has `DropDownExtender` alternative which able to display multi-line text option just by using `<br />` between texts.

Comment: it is `asp:DropDownList` @TetsuyaYamamoto

Comment: Which CSS styling currently used? I found interesting example here: http://jsfiddle.net/t0xicCode/454Lqbz8/. It uses `data-content` attribute which IMHO may be inserted from code-behind for each `asp:ListItem` you have.

Comment: I'm currently using `form-control` css @TetsuyaYamamoto

Comment: What method used for binding data to dropdownlist (using a `List` collection or using `DataTable` taken from database query like `SqlConnection`)? I need to clarify this before using specific HTML/CSS attributes to apply in code-behind.

Comment: I'm populating the dropdownlist using a `List` that is taken from an `SqlConnection DataTable`

I will update my post with my method of populating the dropdownlist for more clearance @TetsuyaYamamoto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `form-control` CSS class, I'm sure that you're using Bootstrap CSS.

In Bootstrap, it is possible to implement multi-line options using `data-content` attribute for `select` element.

*Note:* For 2 first choices available below, ensure any long string value you want to show in `data-content` have `<br />` tag inserted between them (see this example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t0xicCode/454Lqbz8/)). The tag can be inserted by using [`String.Insert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.insert(v=vs.110).aspx) (suggested using additional property that stores wrapped value in `address` class):

```
foreach (var addr in addressAll)
{
    if (addr.address.Length >= [position_index])
    {
        // new property to store wrapped values to be displayed in data-content attribute
        addr.longAddress = addr.address.Insert([position_index], "<br />");
    }
}
```

1) To implement the custom attribute with `asp:DropDownList` server control, add it manually in code-behind after data binding. Here is the code-behind part:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     List<address> addressAll = ... //get table data from SQL that has been returned as a list

     addressDdl.DataSource = addressAll;
     addressDdl.DataTextField = "address";
     addressDdl.DataValueField = "addressID";
     addressDdl.DataBind();
     addressDdl.Items.Insert(0,"--Select--");

     // before transform the list into array, use foreach loop provided above

     var arr = addressAll.ToArray();

     // note: zero-index skipped here
     for (int i = 1; i <= addressDdl.Items.Count; i++)
     {
         // add data-content attribute for select options
         addressDdl.Items[i].Attributes.Add("data-content", arr[i - 1].longAddress.ToString());
     }
}
```

2) As an alternative, a `Repeater` may be used to replace `DropDownList` with plain `select` element, but with `ItemTemplate` to set option attributes:

**ASPX**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptDeliveryAddress" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <select id="addressDdl">
            <option value="">--Select--</option>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
            <option data-content="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "[longAddress]") %>" value="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "[address]") %>"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "[address]") %></option>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </select>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

3) Another way I know to use multi-line dropdown is manipulating width in CSS selector together with `selectPicker`:

**ASPX**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="addressDdl" runat="server" CssClass="form-control selectpicker large-bootstrap-select" ... />
```

**CSS**

```
/* CSS Class */
.bs-container.large-bootstrap-select {
   .dropdown-menu {
      width: 100px; /* set this attribute with desired size in pixels */
      li a span.text {
         word-wrap: break-word;
         white-space: normal;
      }
   }
}
```

**JS**

```
$('#<%= addressDdl.ClientID %>').selectpicker();
```

References:

[How to add a data-attribute to a dropdown menu with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11834920/how-to-add-a-data-attribute-to-a-dropdown-menu-with-c-sharp)

[Is it possible to have multi-line options?](https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select/issues/532)

Answer (score 0):

you can give static `height` and `white-space: initial;` to `select`

```css
#wgtmsr{
 width:150px;  
 height: 50px;
 white-space: initial;
}

#wgtmsr option{
 width:100px;   
}
```

```html
<select name="wgtmsr" id="wgtmsr">
<option value="kg">Kg</option>
<option value="gm">Gm</option>
<option value="pound">Pound</option>
<option value="MetricTon">Metric ton</option>
<option value="litre">Litre</option>
<option value="ounce">OunceOunceOunce OunceOunce OunceOunceOunce</option>
</select>
```